# What is a unix command for deleting the first N characters of a line?

Tags: bash, unix, command, truncate

For example, I might want to:

```
tail -f logfile | grep org.springframework | <command to remove first N characters>
```

I was thinking that `tr` might have the ability to do this but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 506, accepted):

Use `cut`.  Eg. to strip the first 4 characters of each line (i.e. start on the 5th char):

```
tail -f logfile | grep org.springframework | cut -c 5-
```

Comment: do you have any idea of why the pipe doesn't work? when i run essentially that command, 'cut' doesn't print the results to stdout ... if i just run 'tail -f logfile | cut -c 5-' i can see the results ... the problem must be with grep

i'm using cygwin FYI

thanks

Comment: what does happen if you do not add the last pipe and cut ? basically, if you remove the last part of the line  ?

Comment: it "tails" the logfile, filtering it with grep (i.e., all of the lines with "org.springframework" in them are printed to stdout)

when i add the pipe to 'cut' ... it hangs

HOWEVER, if i eliminate 'grep' the 'cut' works properly ... i'm thinking something's wrong with how i'm using grep ... could be a cygwin thing too

Comment: oh i see...why do you use tail ? just do grep org.springframework logfile | cut -c 5-
but i think sed is nicer :-)

Comment: because the '-f' arg to 'tail' causes tail to continuously read the file ... it allows me to view updates to the logfile as they are written

Comment: @les2: probably way to late, but if grep seems to be the culprit why not swap the pipes to: `tail -f logfile |cut -c 5-|grep org.springframework` ?

Comment: The problem is, that grep is buffering big chunks before sending them to cut because it can see that it's not writing to a terminal. Use `grep --line-buffered "org.springframework` to solve that issue.

Comment: what is the - char after the 5-? why

Comment: what if we want to perform the operation on only 1 line not each and every line ??

Answer (score 64):

```
sed 's/^.\{5\}//' logfile
```

and you replace 5 by the number you want...it should do the trick...

**EDIT**
if for each line
  `sed 's/^.\{5\}//g' logfile`

Answer (score 53):

You can use `cut`:

```
cut -c N- file.txt > new_file.txt
```

`-c:` characters

`file.txt:` input file

`new_file.txt:` output file

`N-:` Characters from N to end to be cut and output to the new file.

Can also have other args like: 'N' , 'N-M', '-M' meaning nth character, nth to mth character, first to mth character respectively.

This will perform the operation to each line of the input file.

Answer (score 11):

```
x=hello

echo ${x:1}
```

returns ello

replace 1 with N as required

Answer (score 9):

```
tail -f logfile | grep org.springframework | cut -c 900-
```

would remove the first 900 characters

`cut` uses 900- to show the 900th character to the end of the line

however when I pipe all of this through grep I don't get anything

Comment: "cut -c 1-900" will not "remove the first 900 characters" -- it will leave only the first 900 characters.  If you want to remove the first 900 chars, use "cut -c 901-"

Comment: also it's first 900 characters on each line, per @iammichael's answer

Comment: 'cut -c 900-" will remove the first 899 characters, no?

Answer (score 6):

Here is simple function, tested in bash. 1st param of function is string, 2nd param is number of characters to be stripped

```bash
function stringStripNCharsFromStart {
    echo ${1:$2:${#1}}
}
```

**Usage**:

```bash
$ stringStripNCharsFromStart "12abcdefgh-" 2
# 2abcdefgh-
```

**Screenshot**:

[image: Screenshot of result from console]

Comment: you can simplify this to echo ${1:$2}

Answer (score 4):

I think `awk` would be the best tool for this as it can both filter and perform the necessary string manipulation functions on filtered lines:

```
tail -f logfile | awk '/org.springframework/ {print substr($0, 6)}'
```

or

```
tail -f logfile | awk '/org.springframework/ && sub(/^.{5}/,"",$0)'
```