# Delete the first five characters on any line of a text file in Linux with sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I need a one-liner to remove the first five characters on any line of a text file. How can I do that with sed?

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971879/what-is-a-unix-command-for-deleting-the-first-n-characters-of-a-line

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```sh
sed 's/^.....//'
```

means

*replace ("s", substitute) beginning-of-line then 5 characters (".") with nothing*.

There are more compact or flexible ways to write this using sed or cut.

Comment: How would you do this for the last character of a string?

Comment: @blarg try `sed 's/.$//'`

Comment: plus 1 for answering the 'with sed' part of the question and then mentioning that `cut` is better

Answer (score 183):

Use [`cut`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(Unix)):

```sh
cut -c6-
```

This prints each line of the input starting at column 6 (the first column is 1).

Comment: Here, cut has a better performance than sed, but I got problems when used on utf-8 encoded characters.

Comment: Just to elaborate on @PSchwede's comment, GNU `cut` treats all characters as bytes even when you use the `-c` option. GNU `cut` does not support multi-byte characters and probably will not support multi-byte characters for the foreseeable future

Answer (score 16):

```
sed 's/^.\{,5\}//' file.dat
```

Comment: BSD sed does not accept the *at most* bound (`{,5}`) , this is GNU specific. An expression that works on both would be `sed 's/^.\{5\}//' file.dat`

Answer (score 13):

```
awk '{print substr($0,6)}' file
```