# How to prune local tracking branches that do not exist on remote anymore?

Tags: git, git-branch

With `git remote prune origin` I can remove the local branches that are not  on the remote any more.

But I also want to remove local branches that were created from those remote branches (a check if they are unmerged would be nice).

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove local branches no longer on remote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726949/remove-local-branches-no-longer-on-remote)

Comment: One-liner, cross platform, doesn't look like the cat slept on your keyboard:

`npx git-removed-branches` (dry-run) or
`npx git-removed-branches --prune` (for real).
You need to already have _node.js_ installed.
See [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45699402/11545) [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57748218/11545) for details.

Comment: I usually think these things should be done deliberately not automatic otherwise you open yourself to deleting something you didn't want to delete. So I'd stick with git branch -d localBranchName and git push origin --delete remoteBranchName

Comment: For IntelliJ users the following plugin does exactly what you need: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10059-git-branch-cleaner

Answer (score 1462, accepted):

After pruning, you can get the list of remote branches with `git branch -r`.  The list of branches with their remote tracking branch can be retrieved with `git branch -vv`.  So using these two lists you can find the remote tracking branches that are not in the list of remotes.

This line should do the trick (requires `bash` or `zsh`, won't work with standard Bourne shell):

```sh
git fetch -p ; git branch -r | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v -f /dev/fd/0 <(git branch -vv | grep origin) | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d
```

This string gets the list of remote branches and passes it into `egrep` through the standard input.  And filters the branches that have a remote tracking branch (using `git branch -vv` and filtering for those that have `origin`) then getting the first column of that output which will be the branch name.  Finally passing all the branch names into the delete branch command.

Since it is using the `-d` option, it will not delete branches that have not been merged into the branch that you are on when you run this command.

Comment: This worked for me perfectly. Somehow, ```git fetch -p``` is not always enough?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in Git Bash on Windows.  `sh.exe": cannot make pipe for process substitution: Function not implemented
  sh.exe": egrep -v -f /dev/fd/0: No such file or directory
  fatal: branch name required`  Any ideas?

Comment: This is due `/dev/fd/0` not existing for the stdout in windows, I am not sure what the equivalent would be.

Comment: Great command set. However, if you only have one branch, the command will not `grep -v` out the master line. You can fix this with a simple master culling like so:  `git branch -r | awk '{print }' | grep -v 'master' | egrep -v -f /dev/fd/0 <(git branch -vv | grep origin | grep -v 'master') | xargs git branch -d`

Comment: @Schleis I think `/dev/fd/0` is stdin not stdout.

Comment: Great command. As you said, the branch not fully merged are not deleted. The option -D in `git branch -D` instead of the final `git branch -d` will help if these branches are not relevant to your case.

Comment: fatal: branch name required

Comment: @zgoda that would happen if you don't have any branches that would be deleted.  To check, use everything up to the last pipe in to xargs and see what comes out.

Comment: I love this, but the problem is that for some reason it didn't get rid of even half of my branches.  It did get rid of many, but not all the branches that I was expecting.  Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Did you perform a `git fetch --prune` before running this?  Or are your branches not tracking a remote?  This command only removes the branches whose remote tracking branch doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: For those on Windows, the approach proposed in the answer by @wisbucky worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30494276/315702

Comment: I'm getting an error: `egrep: brackets ([ ]) not balanced` when running this command?

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. In my case it is missing some branches. It seems to me that `branch -vv` writes `[origin/some_branch: gone]` for branches where the remote tracking branch has been removed by the prune? So, the following seems to work for me: `git branch -vv | grep -e ": gone]" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d`

Comment: Oh, I just realised this is exactly what was proposed in http://stackoverflow.com/a/30494276/865169

Comment: Add option `-r` to `xargs` to ignore when there are no branches to remove.

Comment: To add it as an alias: `alias git-remove-untracked='git fetch --prune && git branch -r | awk "{print \$1}" | egrep -v -f /dev/fd/0 <(git branch -vv | grep origin) | awk "{print \$1}" | xargs git branch -d'`

Comment: Is there any proposed command for a future git release that will do this?  This command looks like my cat has been on my laptop

Comment: Absolutely.  This should be built into git.

Comment: This is why I love Linux (and Bash)!!

Comment: Sure @ThomParkin I love them too, but you love them because somehow an extremely convolved command makes up for a being able to perform a common task that Git should handle itself? Though I love Git, it's amazing the overhead it requires for any development team that should be focused on development to remember simple, standard usage.

Comment: Although this works in deleting those branches, I'm getting a bunch of errors for when the pattern matches stuff that isn't a branch, e.g.: "error: branch 'blabla' not found", where 'blabla' is all kinds of simple words or characters, sometimes brackets or just the word branch or handle, as if it took a branch name apart and took every piece of it as its own branch for some reason.

Comment: @Project707 Point taken.  I cannot [entirely] disagree.

Comment: @Project707: I find the convoluted commands eventually boil down to requiring a Turing complete scripting language anyway.

Comment: using `git branch -D` at the end of the command worked better for us, as we tend to squash commits on merge, which gets us `The branch x is not fully merged` errors when running with `-d`.

Comment: For really detailed information, check this out: [explainshell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=git+branch+-r+%7C+awk+%27%7Bprint+%241%7D%27+%7C+egrep+-v+-f+%2Fdev%2Ffd%2F0+%3C%28git+branch+-vv+%7C+grep+origin%29+%7C+awk+%27%7Bprint+%241%7D%27+%7C+xargs+git+branch+-d)

Comment: I got `error: The branch my_local_test_branch is not fully merged`. So, I added `-D` instead of `-d` to clean up the _unmerged_  `my_local_branch` 

The complete command:
`git branch -r | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v -f /dev/fd/0 <(git branch -vv | grep origin) | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -D`

Comment: @mani_jena I would be cautious about using `-D` here. It might remove some topic branch work you have locally that you haven't yet pushed to `origin`!

Comment: I just don't want local branches that are tracking remote branches that don't exist anymore, here's the alias I use:

`alias git_branch_cleanup="git fetch -p && git branch -v | grep '[gone]' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -D"`

Comment: I got an error when making it an alias `awk: syntax error at source line 1`, so I moved it to `/usr/local/bin` so it can run it easily and without issues.

Comment: @MarcoChiappetta I got your point, but, what if the branch was never tracked by any remote? I believe in this case, using the `-D` could get rid of WIP.

Comment: @Ludder you can use Windows Subsystem on Linux for this. I just tested it and it worked. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: Works fine in Git Bash for Windows now. Seems the problem that existed earlier was fixed.

Comment: Works for me, caveat a couple items: 1) set the name of the remote correctly (if not origin), 2) If your branches are not merged (for example, you do squash merges) use "-D" instead of "-d" in the last step.

Comment: Why isn't there something like 'git delete-untracked-branches', why on earth do we need to learn this convoluted nonsense.

Comment: Totally unnecessary why would you use that instead of two commands, one to prune remote, and one to delete the local branch? There's a lot to be said for keeping things simple and transparent.

Comment: @ludder This works for Git Bash on Windows 10 without WSL for me, it can probably be shortened: `git branch | sed 's/\x1b[[0-9]*m//g' | cut -c3- | cut -f1 -d' ' | awk '{print $1}' | grep -E -v $(git branch -r | sed 's/origin\///g' | sed 's/\x1b[[0-9]*m//g' | cut -c3- | cut -f1 -d' ' | xargs | sed 's/ /|/g' | awk '{print $1}') | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -D` Code Credits: schleis, this answer, mateus-gondim, a comment on this answer, greg-hewgill, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3795522/6533028 and oliv, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36550261/6533028

Comment: I like this variation `git fetch -p && awk '/origin/&&/gone/{print $1}' <(git branch -vv) | xargs git branch -D`

Comment: For Windows Powershell: `git fetch -p; git branch --merged | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -ne "* master") { git branch -d $_.Trim() } }`
Note that it will delete all branches which have been merged to master. If your primary branch is different, change master to your branch name.

Answer (score 647):

If you want to delete all local branches that are already merged into master, you can use the following command:

```
git branch --merged master | grep -v '^[ *]*master$' | xargs -d'\n' git branch -d
```

If you are using `main` as your master branch, you should modify the command accordingly:

```
git branch --merged main | grep -v '^[ *]*main$' | xargs -d'\n' git branch -d
```

[More info](http://devblog.springest.com/a-script-to-remove-old-git-branches).

NOTE: `xargs` `-d'\n'` parameter is used to allow proper deletion of branches with an apostrophe in the name, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38148/why-does-xargs-strip-quotes-from-input.

Comment: Worked perfect, I think! Could anyone explain if this answer does anything differently than the accepted answer?

Comment: Is it possible to turn this into a global git alias?  I tried this but it didn't work:

`git config --global alias.cleaner "branch --merged master | grep -v 'master$' | xargs branch -d"`

Comment: Branches ending on 'master' won't be deleted. I use

`git branch --merged master | grep -v '^  master$' | xargs git branch -d`

just because it matches how it is formatted in git branch output

Comment: This is great, I would say an improvement would be to remove master from the `git branch --merged master` command.  This allows you to base this on the current branch.  In my case (we're using git flow) I wanted to delete all branches that weren't merged into develop (my current branch).

Comment: Minor improvement: use `xargs -r git branch -d` so that nothing is run if there are no branches to delete. Note that the `-r` flag [may not be available everywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812766/dont-call-xargs-if-the-previous-command-doesnt-return-anything)

Comment: This is great but I do not see how it answers the question. If I delete a branch on the remote that is not merged into master then this command will delete a bunch of other local branches but leave the branch whose remote tracking branch was deleted. No?

Comment: Since grep may not match due to git colors: `git branch --merged master --no-color | grep -v '^* master$' | xargs -n1 -r git branch -d`

Comment: @NickRes seeing as you asked so nicely, `git branch --merged master` lists branches that are merged into master, then the middle grep part excludes master itself (we don't want to delete master!), and the last xargs part executes `git branch -d` (delete branch) on each of the results. Or you could just read the More info link provided in the answer ;)

Comment: Improvement: `git branch --merged master | egrep -v '^\s*\*?\s*master$' | xargs git branch -d`. Output from git v2.10.1 will display "* master" when master is checked out. I get rid of master both with or without an asterisk.

Comment: @Esteban similar fix added - catches your case. (jackocnr hope you don't mind the edit - it wasn't excluding master on git 2.14 as it was)

Comment: @mgcdanny (and anyone else interested): in order to make this a global `git` alias, you need to do (in `~/.gitconfig` or other config file): `cleaner = !git branch --merged master | grep -v '^[ *]*master$' | xargs git branch -d`

Comment: I am using `git branch --merged develop | egrep -v 'develop$|master$ | xargs -r git branch -d` on my develop branch.  Not sure how best practice the specific regular expression is, but thanks for the help.

Comment: This does work only if remote branch exists. If the branch is removed after merged into the master - this approach won't work.

Comment: Now that github [encourages the primary branch to be called `main`](https://github.com/github/renaming), the command written by @Esteban would be `git branch --merged main | egrep -v '^\s*\*?\s*main$' | xargs git branch -d`

Comment: @MatthewCox thanks for adding a comment that will help quite a few people. However, it's GitHub specific.

Comment: @Esteban GitLab ist also changing "master" to "main" https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/03/10/new-git-default-branch-name/

Comment: My own improvement: `( git branch --merged origin/main; git branch --merged origin/master ) 2>/dev/null | tr -d '*' | grep -Ev '^ *(main|master)$' | xargs -r git branch -d`  This is agnostic towards master or main (as long as no madman created them both...), uses origin instead of local main in case you haven't pulled it, removes asterisk from _all_ branches in case main is not the one currently checked out (nobody is using asterisks as part of their branch names... right?) and includes `-r` for xargs in case no branches are listed.

Comment: *agnostic towards master or main (as long as no madman created them both...)*  Heh, heh, this actually happens easily when you use 2 remotes and one has the woke policy and the other does not...

Comment: @Andrew this deletes merged branches. There're other reasons for a local branch to not have a remote counterpart.

Comment: 10 years and 600k views later, why is this still not a single instruction?

Answer (score 272):

Amidst the information presented by `git help fetch`, there is this little item:

```
 -p, --prune
        After fetching, remove any remote-tracking branches which no longer exist on the remote.
```

So, perhaps, `git fetch -p` is what you are looking for?

EDIT: Ok, for those still debating this answer 3 years after the fact, here's a little more information on why I presented this answer...

First, the OP says they want to "remove also those local branches that were created from those remote branches [that are not any more on the remote]". This is not unambiguously possible in `git`. Here's an example.

Let's say I have a repo on a central server, and it has two branches, called `A` and `B`. If I clone that repo to my local system, my clone will have local refs (not actual branches yet) called `origin/A` and `origin/B`. Now let's say I do the following:

```
git checkout -b A origin/A
git checkout -b Z origin/B
git checkout -b C <some hash>
```

The pertinent facts here are that I for some reason chose to create a branch on my local repo that has a different name than its origin, and I also have a local branch that does not (yet) exist on the origin repo.

Now let's say I remove both the `A` and `B` branches on the remote repo and update my local repo (`git fetch` of some form), which causes my local refs `origin/A` and `origin/B` to disappear. Now, my local repo has three branches still, `A`, `Z`, and `C`. None of these have a corresponding branch on the remote repo. Two of them were "created from ... remote branches", but even if I know that there used to be a branch called `B` on the origin, I have no way to know that `Z` was created from `B`, because it was renamed in the process, probably for a good reason. So, really, without some external process recording branch origin metadata, or a human who knows the history, it is impossible to tell which of the three branches, if any, the OP is targeting for removal. Without some external information that `git` does not automatically maintain for you, `git fetch -p` is about as close as you can get, and any automatic method for literally attempting what the OP asked runs the risk of either deleting too many branches, or missing some that the OP would otherwise want deleted.

There are other scenarios, as well, such as if I create three separate branches off `origin/A` to test three different approaches to something, and then `origin/A` goes away. Now I have three branches, which obviously can't all match name-wise, but they were created from `origin/A`, and so a literal interpretation of the OPs question would require removing all three. However, that may not be desirable, if you could even find a reliable way to match them...

Comment: This doesn't delete the local branches, only the remote pointers to the branches

Comment: It deletes only these local branches, which does not exist in remote AND you never did a checkout on them.

Comment: You should read the question more carefully as Jaap notes. People voting for this answer should also read what the question is really about.

Comment: Yes, this was actually exactly what I wanted to do! @SørenBoisen I hope in the last two years you've had time to revisit that opinion of yours... If content posted on SO should always be only related to what sometimes really confused OPs ask, we would remove a lot of information. Please don't presume to instruct people how they can use this site, other than the official guidelines, and they clearly do not prevent orthogonal yet useful answers.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Here is my issue with this answer: 1) The question is crystal clear, OP is clearly not confused. 2) This answer does not mention that it does not answer the question! 3) The question already states a way to prune remote-tracking branches which no longer exist, so it adds zero value.

Comment: Answers are for more than the op. Nearly a hundred people find this useful. Of course it adds value!!

Comment: git fetch --prune does what I wanted it to do (trimming local branches that don't exist in the remote) - and the more upvoted bash-based answers don't. Therefore, I think this adds value and is worthy of an upvote.

Comment: Even if the local branch names do not match the upstream branches, Git still tracks that these branches track an upstream branch and this could be used to delete branches. In `.git/config`, there are entries for each such branch and its upstream name. Thus Git could use this information for pruning of local branches. It's simply a missing feature.

Comment: @siride Exactly, not only does this answer not answer the question, it presents a whole ton of incorrect information regarding remote tracking and how git works.

Answer (score 217):

There's a [neat npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-removed-branches) that does it for you (and it should work cross platform).

Install it with: `npm install -g git-removed-branches`

And then `git removed-branches` will show you all the stale local branches, and `git removed-branches --prune` to actually delete them.

[More info here.](https://github.com/nemisj/git-removed-branches)

Comment: This should really have more upvotes. Thanks for making life easy, regardless of platform.

Comment: Handy little extension. Installed and worked fine on Windows 10. Little note: it considers non-merged branches as prune-able (error when running --prune, just though branch -d was called) .. they are however, not denoted as such in the initial listing shown.

Comment: This is my favorite answer. `npx git-removed-branches` works like a dream.

Comment: yes! This should have more upvotes! so simple and intuitive solution for cli's newbie

Comment: It would be useful to give an overview of what the tool is doing from git's perspective.

Comment: Worked great for me. Make sure to run it from the default branch. +1

Comment: @ryanwebjackson The project is on Github: https://github.com/nemisj/git-removed-branches

Comment: This should be native git functionality IMO. Nice!

Answer (score 179):

This will delete the local branches for which the remote tracking branches have been pruned. (Make sure you are on `master` branch!)

```
git checkout master
git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d
```

---

Details:

- `git branch -vv` displays "gone" for local branches that the remote has been pruned.

  ```
  mybranch abc1234 [origin/mybranch: gone] commit comments
  ```
- `-d` will check if it has been merged (`-D` will delete it regardless)

  ```
  error: The branch 'mybranch' is not fully merged.
  ```

Comment: You can even make the command shorter with `git branch -vv | awk '/: gone]/{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d`

Comment: Just pointing out that you should be on master before doing this, because `git branch -d` compares branches against `HEAD`.

Comment: Excellent! I looked and looked for this. I wish I had seen your answer before I ended up figuring it out on my own.  It would have saved me a few minutes. Here's my other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661853/list-all-local-branches-without-a-remote/34969726#34969726

Comment: I ended up with a similar git alias, used cut since awk did not work for some reason: `prunelocal = !sh -c \"git checkout -q master && git fetch -q --prune && git branch -vv | git grep ': gone]' | cut -d' ' -f3 | xargs git branch -d\"`

Comment: This only worked after I did `git fetch --prune`. If I tried to combine that with the rest, it broke, trying to delete all the "branches" whose names were the output of the fetch.

Comment: Very useful, specially when remote branches are rebased or squashed instead of merged. Adding prune, this will delete any branches make as "gone": ```git fetch -p; git branch -vv | awk '/: gone]/{print $1}' | xargs git branch -D```

Comment: Oh dude... wisbucky you NEED to update your answer to tell people they should be on master. Just did this from a different branch. @stevebennet2 thanks for the informative comment

Comment: `git branch -vv | awk '/^[^*].*: gone]/{print $1}''` will not show `*` if current branch is also gone.

Comment: The `: gone]` part is a localized string. For french version you must use `: disparue]`.

Comment: For anyone deciding to use `xargs git branch -D`, note that `-D` flag is essentially a "force-delete" but is necessary for deleting branches where the remote branch was squash-merged or rebased, so as a good middleground, I would suggest prompting for user confirmation before each delete (safer); using `xargs -p git branch -D`

Comment: To get it work correctly run this command first: `git remote prune origin`

Answer (score 98):

#### Windows Solution

For Microsoft Windows Powershell:

```bash
git checkout master; git remote update origin --prune; git branch -vv | Select-String -Pattern ": gone]" | % { $_.toString().Trim().Split(" ")[0]} | % {git branch -d $_}
```

#### Explanation

`git checkout master` switches to the master branch

`git remote update origin --prune` prunes remote branches

`git branch -vv` gets a verbose output of all branches ([git reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch--vv))

`Select-String -Pattern ": gone]"` gets only the records where they have been removed from remote.

`% { $_.toString().Split(" ")[0]}` get the branch name

`% {git branch -d $_}` deletes the branch

Comment: Nice example. alternatively use `git remote prune origin`, also select-string doesn't seem to match with the latest version of git. Consider using `ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent`

Comment: Looks like the latest version of git adds some trailing spaces, so the Split doesn't work to get the branch name. Do .toString().Trim().Split(" ") and it will

Comment: Here is mine: `git checkout master; git pull; git remote prune origin; git branch --merged | select-string -notmatch "master" | % { $_.toString().Trim().Split(" ")[0]} | % {git branch -d $_}`

Comment: @Omzig What does that do differently?  Can you give an explanation>

Comment: @chris31389, i have the pull in there to get everything that i am missing from master, and i changed the branch to --merged and not master, i want to make sure that i only delete the --merged branches. It just makes me feel better ;)

Comment: This works quite nicely for PowerShell Core i.e., it's a cross platform solution.

Comment: I got: `error: The branch 'bugfix/foobar' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D bugfix/foobar'.`, so for me it worked using a upper case d at the end `{git branch -D $_}`

Comment: I had to run `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Utf8` before the command so that branches with non ansi characters get deleted as well, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690793/the-powershell-call-operator-set-the-output-encoding

Answer (score 70):

One can configure Git to automatically remove references to deleted remote branches when fetching:

```
git config --global fetch.prune true
```

When calling `git fetch` or `git pull` afterwards, references to deleted remote branches get removed automatically.

Comment: this does not remove local branches, just references to them, right?

Comment: @ClintEastwood It only deletes references to *remote* branches. You can list references to remote branches using `git branch -r`.

Answer (score 61):

As @tzacks notes... there is an npm package that is handy for this.  Just do:

```
npx git-removed-branches --prune
```

(I would have commented but not enough reputation)

Comment: Gorgeous. No hassle whatsoever.  Glad this was a full answer!

Comment: This should be at the top. Works in Windows too.

Comment: zero hassle! it'd be at the top if it didn't require npx

Answer (score 54):

It will list the local branches whose remote tracking branch is deleted from remote

```
$ git remote prune origin --dry-run
```

If you want to de-reference these local branches from local which are un tracked

```
$ git remote prune origin
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, this is what the OP already knew.

Comment: I also agree, but when you search "How to prune local tracking branches that do not exist on remote anymore", this is the top link and this answer matches with the title (not if one has read the full description in question), that is the reason for up votes:)

Comment: This does not remove the local branches. Still there after running this

Comment: @Xin try running the command without --dry-run argument as it will not actually execute the command, but show you what it will change.

Comment: This is precisely what I needed. I had an old branch showing up as a remote branch locally that didn't exist on the server.

Answer (score 24):

If using Windows and Powershell, you can use the following to delete all local branches that have been merged into the branch currently checked out:

```
git branch --merged | ? {$_[0] -ne '*'} | % {$_.trim()} | % {git branch -d $_}
```

Explanation

- Lists the current branch and the branches that have been merged into it
- Filters out the current branch
- Cleans up any leading or trailing spaces from the `git` output for each remaining branch name
- Deletes the merged local branches

It's worth running `git branch --merged` by itself first just to make sure it's only going to remove what you expect it to.

(Ported/automated from http://railsware.com/blog/2014/08/11/git-housekeeping-tutorial-clean-up-outdated-branches-in-local-and-remote-repositories/.)

Comment: This will delete all merged branches versus just those that are marked as deleted on the remote.  This could be undesirable if you have environment or release branches that have been merged but we want to keep around (like `uat` `prod` etc).

Answer (score 20):

Even shorter and safer one-liner:

```
git branch -d $(git branch --merged | cut -c 3- | grep -v master)
```

Be sure to checkout to branch that is not merged yet, before run it. Because you can not delete branch that you are currently checked in.

Comment: will this also remove your 'master' ?

Comment: If you currently checked into master then no, otherwise yea

Comment: To skip master you could just pipe to grep and select the inverse, like so -
 `git branch -d $(git branch --merged | cut -c 3- | grep -v master)`

Comment: This is unsafe and someone in the future will unknowingly delete their master branch

Comment: @jasonseminara #dcsan I have updated snippet, so it skips master branch.
#mozillalives thanks

Comment: Someone in the future will unknowingly delete their "development" branch

Answer (score 20):

I wanted something that would purge all local branches that were tracking a remote branch, on `origin`, where the remote branch has been deleted (`gone`). I did not want to delete local branches that were never set up to track a remote branch (i.e.: my local dev branches). Also, I wanted a simple one-liner that just uses `git`, or other simple CLI tools, rather than writing custom scripts. I ended up using a bit of `grep` and `awk` to make this simple command, then added it as an alias in my `~/.gitconfig`.

```
[alias]
  prune-branches = !git remote prune origin && git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -r git branch -D
```

Here is a `git config --global ...` command for easily adding this as `git prune-branches`:

```
git config --global alias.prune-branches '!git remote prune origin && git branch -vv | grep '"'"': gone]'"'"' | awk '"'"'{print $1}'"'"' | xargs -r git branch -d'
```

NOTE: Use of the `-D` flag to `git branch` can be very dangerous. So, in the config command above I use the `-d` option to `git branch` rather than `-D`; I use `-D` in my actual config. I use `-D` because I don't want to hear Git complain about unmerged branches, I just want them to go away. You may want this functionality as well. If so, simply use `-D` instead of `-d` at the end of that config command.

Answer (score 14):

Here is my solution :

```
git fetch -p
git branch -vv | grep ": gone" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d
```

- **-p** is to remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote. So first step will remove references to remote branches.
- **-vv** is for showing sha1 and commit subject line for each head, along with relationship to upstream branch (if any). 2nd step will get all the local branches and grep command will filter out branches that have been deleted.

Comment: Even smaller (as described in another comment) `git branch -vv | awk '/: gone]/{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d`

Comment: I had to make the final `-d` a `-D`, otherwise your second line would give me this output on each branch:
`error: The branch 'your-branch' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D your-branch'.`

Answer (score 12):

There doesn't seem to be a safe one-liner, too many edge cases (like a branch having "master" as part of its name, etc). Safest is these steps:

1. `git branch -vv | grep 'gone]' > stale_branches.txt`
2. view the file and remove lines for branches you want to keep (such as master branch!); you don't need to edit the contents of any line
3. `awk '{print $1}' stale_branches.txt | xargs git branch -d`

Answer (score 9):

To remove remote branches:

```
$git remote prune origin
```

To remove local branches that are already merged:

```
$git branch -D $(git branch --merged)
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.

Comment: (git branch --merged) also returns 'master' for me.  And other branches that haven't been deleted on the remote.

Comment: This deleted my master branch.

Comment: Maybe better: `$git branch -D $(git branch --merged | egrep -v '^\*|^\s+master$')` thus filtering out master and the current branch.

Comment: does `git branch  --no-contains <main_or_master> --merged`  work here?

Answer (score 8):

This command and the script below work in Linux and Windows with Git Bash (MinGW).

It is best to use git's internal commands so that comments or names don't accidentally match and delete a branch that you don't want to delete. There are many internal "atoms" that can be used with `git for-each-ref`'s format option to output the desired information.  This way we don't have to rely on piping to `awk` or `grep` to check a regular expression on output that may contain unnecessary information.

The command below uses only `git for-each-ref`'s internal low level commands to list only orphaned local branches. Once you have these you can pipe to `git branch -D`.  Also, don't forget to prune and fetch your remote references first, or it won't find any matches:

```
git fetch -p
git for-each-ref --format '%(if:equals=[gone])%(upstream:track)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)' 'refs/heads/**' | xargs -r git branch -D
```

Here is a breakdown:

`git fetch -p` - prune removed references and fetch new ones from the remote

`git for-each-ref --format` - lists all references using a specific output format.

`%(if:equals=[gone])%(upstream:track)` - only output if the upstream tracking branch is "[gone]".

`%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)` - output the branch name (when tracking is gone).

`refs/heads/**` - limit to head references (for efficiency).

`| xargs -r git branch -D` - pipe output as parameters for deletion.  The `-r` indicates to ignore blank input.

---

By itself, this solution is long, ridiculous to type, and hard to remember.  Luckily, adding custom commands to git is easy.  Below is a script that uses the same command above, but it allows the user to see which branches will be selected with a `--dry-run` option.

I named my file `git-prune-local` and dropped it in a folder that was included on my `PATH`.  It also needs execution permissions (`chmod 755 git-prune-local`).

Git automatically looks for executable files like `git-[command]`.  With this, you only need to type `git prune-local` for the correct branches to be deleted.

**git-prune-local**

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -gt 1 ] || ([ ! -z $1 ] && [ $1 != "--dry-run" ])
then
    echo "Usage: git prune-local [--dry-run]"
    exit
fi

git fetch -p --quiet
branchesToDelete=$(git for-each-ref --format '%(if:equals=[gone])%(upstream:track)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)' 'refs/heads/**')

while read -r branch
do
    if [ ! -z $branch ]
    then
        if [ ! -z $1 ]
        then
            echo $branch
        else
            git branch -D $branch
        fi
    fi
done <<< "$branchesToDelete"
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`--no-contains`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---no-containsltcommitgt) option to avoid removing your `master` branch when using branch `--merged`.

Running alone this looks like

```
$ git branch --no-contains master --merged master
    old-branch1
    old-branch2
    old-branch3
```

To delete the branches in Unix shell using `xargs`

```
git branch --no-contains master --merged master | xargs git branch -d
```

To delete the branches in Powershell using Pipes

```
git.exe branch --no-contains master --merged master `
    | foreach { git.exe branch -v -d $_.Trim() }
```

Answer (score 6):

In **Powershell**:

```
git branch -D (git branch --merged |% { $_.trim() } )
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on the answers above I'm using this shorter one liner:

```
git remote prune origin | awk 'BEGIN{FS="origin/"};/pruned/{print $2}' | xargs -r git branch -d
```

Also, if you already pruned and have local dangling branches, then this will clean them up:

```
git branch -vv | awk '/^ .*gone/{print $1}' | xargs -r git branch -d
```

Comment: Doesn't work if your branch names have a `/` in them

Answer (score 5):

On OS X, which supports `cut -w`

```
git branch -d $(git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' | cut -w -f 2 )
```

##### explanation

###### delete following branches

```
git branch -d ...
```

##### show removed branches

```
$ git branch -vv | grep ': gone]'
  chore/TECH-456   a4bdac8ac8 [origin/TECH-456: gone] chore: syntax error
  feature/TECH-678 0342f8e277 [origin/feature/TECH-678: gone] Added IsGross in new Income Details
```

##### keep the branch name

```
$ git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' | cut -w -f 2
chore/TECH-456
feature/TECH-678
```

Answer (score 4):

not sure how to do it all at once, but git `git branch -d <branchname>` will delete a local branch ONLY if it is completely merged. Note the lowercase d.

`git branch -D <branchname>` (note the capital D) will delete a local branch regardless of its merged status.

Comment: On Windows, the other answers did not work for me. Using this answer with the simple -D switch did (even though the branch had already been "deleted").

Comment: Can we do it for all branches at once?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by a few simple actions:

- Output your all branches into a temp file:

```
git branch > branches.tmp
```

- Open the file and remove branches to exclude them from being deleted from your local (branches like `develop`/`master`/`main`/`...`)
- Pass branches name to `xargs` by `cat` command and remove branches:

```
cat branches.tmp | xargs git branch -D
```

Answer (score 3):

Schleis' variant does not work for me (Ubuntu 12.04), so let me propose my (clear and shiny :) variants:

Variant 1 (I would prefer this option):

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short) %(upstream)' refs/heads/ | awk '$2 !~/^refs\/remotes/' | xargs git branch -D
```

Variant 2:

a. Dry-run:

```
comm -23 <( git branch | grep -v "/" | grep -v "*" | sort ) <( git br -r | awk -F '/' '{print $2}' | sort ) | awk '{print "git branch -D " $1}'
```

b. Remove branches:

```
comm -23 <( git branch | grep -v "/" | grep -v "*" | sort ) <( git br -r | awk -F '/' '{print $2}' | sort ) | xargs git branch -D
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this command:

```
git branch --merged master | grep -v "\* master" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

[Git Clean: Delete Already-Merged Branches](https://stevenharman.net/git-clean-delete-already-merged-branches) including break down of command

Comment: You don't really need to filter out any branches (ex master).  If it's "merged" then that just means it'll remove your local copy, but "git checkout dev" will create a local branch from remote if not already present

Comment: But the local branch list are still there even if they are merged. This command is to remove these branches which have been deleted from remote.

Comment: asterisk on the beginning means current branch, when you run that command on different branch will not works well

Answer (score 3):

This works for me using git 2.21.0 - it deletes local tracking branches which are merged into `HEAD` where I have previously `--set-upstream` on push (I use `push.default=upstream` because it works best with multiple remotes) and that upstream branch has since been deleted by a `fetch --prune` (or implicitly if `fetch.prune=true` in git config):

```
git branch -vv --merged | grep ': gone]' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d
```

The use of `--merged` and `-d` make this a very 'safe' delete. A more aggressive version could drop the `--merged` and use `-D`

Comment: Note you have to checkout a branch that tracks an existing remote branch, else the command right before piping to `xargs` will return `*` instead of the branch name. My suggestion is to use `git checkout master; git branch -vv --merged | grep ': gone]' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d`

Answer (score 3):

On Windows with Powershell, to delete all local branches that have been deleted on the remote, regardless of merge status, this will do the trick:

```
git fetch -p
git branch --v | ? {$_.contains('[gone]')} | % {$_.trim().split()[0].trim()} | % {git branch -D $_}
```

- `git branch --v` Gives verbose list of your branches, critically including the `[gone]` status
- `? {$_.contains('[gone]')}` True if `[gone]` is present
- `% {$_.trim().split()[0].trim()}` Gives us just the branch name
- `% {git branch -D $_}` Forced delete of local branch, even if unmerged

If you want to avoid unmerged branches change `-D` to `-d` and handle those manually.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answers above I came with this one line solution:

```
git remote prune origin; git branch -r | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v -f /dev/fd/0 <(git branch -vv | grep origin) | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a variant on @wisbucky's answer, I added the following as an alias to my `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
pruneitgood = "!f() { \
    git remote prune origin; \
    git branch -vv | perl -nae 'system(qw(git branch -d), $F[0]) if $F[3] eq q{gone]}'; \
}; f"
```

With this, a simple `git pruneitgood` will clean up both local & remote branches that are no longer needed after merges.

Answer (score 2):

Following is an adaptation of @wisbucky's answer for Windows users:

`for /f "tokens=1" %i in ('git branch -vv ^| findstr ": gone]"') DO git branch %i -d`

I use posh-git and unfortunately PS doesn't like the naked `for`, so I created a plain 'ol command script named PruneOrphanBranches.cmd:

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('git branch -vv ^| findstr ": gone]"') DO CALL :ProcessBranch %%i %1

GOTO :EOF

:ProcessBranch
IF /I "%2%"=="-d" (
    git branch %1 %2
) ELSE (
    CALL :OutputMessage %1
)
GOTO :EOF

:OutputMessage
ECHO Will delete branch [%1] 
GOTO :EOF

:EOF
```

Call it with no parameters to see a list, and then call it with "-d" to perform the actual deletion or "-D" for any branches that are not fully merged but which you want to delete anyway.

Comment: This didn't work for me, somehow the `:` or `: ` (with a space) in `findstr` caused it to match everything every time--I almost deleted master. However, using a regex worked fine: `git branch -vv ^| findstr /R " \[origin/[0-9]+: gone\] "`

Answer (score 2):

The Powershell Version of `git branch --merged master | grep -v '^[ *]*master$' | xargs git branch -d`

`git branch --merged master | %{ if($_ -notmatch '\*.*master'){ git branch -d "$($_.Trim())" }}`

This will remove any local branches that have been merged into master, *while you are on the master branch*.

`git checkout master` to switch.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in git bash, to fetch and prune references to deleted branches, and then prune the local branches that were tracking the removed ones:

```
git fetch -p && git branch -d `git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs`
```

Remember to checkout first a branch that won't be deleted, so that does not block the deleting of the branch.

Answer (score 0):

I reached this page seeking the answer for "how do I delete locally checked out branches that no longer have an upstream branch"

I also did not care whether or not the local branch had been merged in yet, since piping into `git branch -d` will simply warn instead of deleting unmerged local branches.

```
git branch -a | grep origin | tr -s ' ' | cut -d '/' -f3 | egrep -v -f /dev/fd/0 <(git branch -a | grep -v origin) | grep branch_prefix_that_I_care_about | xargs git branch -d

# translation
# git branch -a | grep origin | tr -s ' ' | cut -d '/' -f3
## this finds all remote branch names minus the "remote/origin/" part
#
# <(git branch -a | grep -v origin)
## this finds all local branch names and redirects it into the previous command
#
# egrep -v -f /dev/fd/0 STUFF
## this is doing some weird magic that I'm grokking as "take the set difference from whatever was piped in"
#
#
# overall translation: (STUFF TO CONSIDER) | egrep magic <(STUFF TO REMOVE FROM CONSIDERATION) | do cool things with resulting stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the answers here usefull when the remote itself does not exist anymore.
I kept seing branches of remotes that did not exist anymore, but did not find a git command to delete them.

The solution for me was to go to the `.git\refs\remotes` directory and directly delete the files that are not relevant any more. The file structure is very easy to understand. It is the same structure as what you see with `git branch -r`.

Answer (score 0):

check for targets

`for target in $(git branch | grep -Eiv "master|develop|branchYouWantToLive"); do echo $target; done`

run with for & subcommands

`for target in $(git branch | grep -Eiv "master|develop|branchYouWantToLive"); do git branch -D $target; done`

you can extend other something works about branches.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Schleis answer (which works perfectly), this can be integrated into Visual Studio, so pruning local branches when a git repo is open in VS is really simple.

You can use the **External Tools** functionality to call sh.exe (git bash) with a specific directory and command. This is located in the Tools > External Tools menu option (in VS 2022 17.1.0). The parameters I use are as follows:

**Command**: `{Path-To-Git-Installation-Location}\bin\sh.exe`

**Arguments**: `--cd=$(SolutionDir) -c "git fetch -p ; git branch -r | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v -f /dev/fd/0 <(git branch -vv | grep origin) | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d"`

**Initial Directory**: `$(SolutionDir)`

[Screenshot of Git Prune Local Branches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4OfD.png)

It's worth noting that this will work only when the solution you have open in VS is within a git repo directory.

Final note - this can be keybound via the Visual Studio key binding user interface in Settings > General > Keyboard and searching for **Tools.ExternalCommand[n]** where n is the position in the External Command table that you have this external tool positioned at (they can be reordered in the Tools > External Tools dialog). See screenshot below.

[Keybinding an External Tools Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpzfF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I love the approach below. I have it im my history and just type `gfa + UP` to get the latest shell-history item starting with `gfa` and I'm done. It works for me for 6 years already.

```bash
gfa && gco develop && gl && for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format '%(refname) %(upstream:track)' refs/heads | awk '$2 == "[gone]" {sub("refs/heads/", "", $1); print $1}' | egrep -v '\*|master|main|develop'); do git branch -d $branch; done
```

The aliases used here resolve to (.zshrc compatible format):

```
alias gfa='git fetch --all --prune --jobs=10'
alias gco='git checkout'
alias gl='git pull'
alias gb='git --no-pager branch'
```

Answer (score -1):

I have turned the accepted answer into a robust script. You'll find it [in my git-extensions repository](https://github.com/inkarkat/git-extensions/blob/master/bin/git-rprune).

```
$ git-rprune --help
Remove old local branches that do not exist in REMOTE any more.
With --test, only print which local branches would be deleted.
Note: To do this automatically on each fetch / pull:
    git config --global fetch.prune true
Usage: git-rprune REMOTE [-t|--test|-f|--force] [-?|-h|--help]
```

Comment: The link no longer works.  Also, won't this conflict the the stock `git prune`?

Comment: @Macadameane Sorry for the broken link; I had moved the script into the `bin/` subdirectory. I've also renamed it to `git-rprune` to avoid that name clash; actually, I never invoke that command directly, but use an alias `oprune=rprune origin`. I'd never seen the built-in `git prune` so far, as it's an uncommon low-level command.

Answer (score -2):

Delete any branch that isn't up to date with master

```
git co master && git branch | sed s/\*/\ / | xargs git branch -d 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm pretty sure that `git remote prune origin` is what you want.

You can run it as `git remote prune origin --dry-run` to see what it *would* do without making any changes.

Comment: This doesn't actually remove the local branch itself.

Answer (score -10):

Using the GUI? Manual procedure, but quick and easy.

```
$ git gui
```

Select "Branch -> Delete". You can select multiple branches with ctrl-click (windows) and remove all of them.

Comment: It's funny how negative this answer is being perceived. Totally valid approach IMO if you like GUI.