# Remove git branches not on remote

Tags: git, merge

A very similar question has already been asked here: [Remove local branches no longer on remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726949/remove-branches-no-longer-on-remote)

But answers given refer to branches merged into master. I want to remove all branches on my machine that do not have a reference on remote.

Example: I carry out some work on a feature branch `feat-improvements`, that gets pushed to remote, reviewed, merged to master, and deleted by the reviewer on remote. But I forgot to get rid of the branch locally by using the standard `git branch -D feat-improvements`, subsequently I've created a whole load of other other fix/feature branches I want to get rid of. now I want to get rid of now in one hit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prune local tracking branches that do not exist on remote anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064613/how-to-prune-local-tracking-branches-that-do-not-exist-on-remote-anymore)

Answer (score -1):

try something like this:

```
git branch -D `git branch | grep -E '(?!branch-that-will-not-be-deleted|another-branch-to-avoid).+'`
```

It uses one regex that ignore everything on the output of git branch (get all the branchs) that match the name `branch-that-will-not-be-deleted` e `another-branch-to-avoid`.

So the argument passed to `git branch -D` will be all the branchs except the explicted in the regex.