# How do I remove deleted Git branches from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio continues to show any branch I've pulled, even after that branch has been deleted (and I do not have it as the selected branch).

- "`git fetch --all --prune`" does not remove them. git config
- "`remote.origin.prune true`" ([suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302588/visual-studio-2013-remove-deleted-git-branches)) does not remove them.

How can I remove the deleted branches from my system?

**Update:** I want an approach that determines what branches are gone and deletes them. If we select them specifically then sooner or later someone will delete a branch in use by mistake.

Comment: Has the branch been deleted locally, remotely, or both? On the off chance you have local copies still hanging around.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`prune` is about removing any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote.

So if the branch still exists on the remote side, it won't be deleted locally.

If the branch is [deleted locally (with Visual Studio)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/delete-branch), its remote tracking instance will still be re-created at the next push.

You need to make sure the branch is [also deleted on the remote side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23961231/6309):

```
git push origin --delete abranch
```

Comment: I don't want to delete a branch, I want to safely delete all local copies of branches that are deleted. And by safely, I want to do it in a way where I don't by mistake delete a branch that does still exist.

Comment: @DavidThielen then https://stackoverflow.com/a/41611648/6309 should work.

Comment: If you mean "git config --global fetch.prune true" it doesn't. I ran that followed by "git fetch --all --prune", exited and restarted Visual Studio - and deleted repositories I once opened are still listed. thanks - dave

Comment: @DavidThielen "deleted repositories"? I thought you want deleted branches removed. A branch is not a repository.

Comment: Sorry - deleted branches. I want to get rid of branches that no longer exist.

Comment: @DavidThielen If those branches no longer exist on the remote side, the `git fetch --prune --all` is supposed to delete them locally. Can you try a `git branch -avv` in the repo after said `git fetch --all --prune`? (in order to check with Git alone if this is working, before checking Visual Studio)

Comment: Hi;  Sorry, didn't do it. Still lists branches that were deleted over a month ago.

Comment: @DavidThielen Sure. Now, can you try a `git branch -avv` in the repo after said `git fetch --all --prune`?

Comment: "git branch -avv" lists 5 branches as gone (they are) and 3 as behind (what does that mean?). So it tells me which ones are safe to delete. If that's the best that can be done, that works. thanks - dave

Comment: @DavidThielen At this point, I think we need the exact output (as well a the output of git remote -v): this should be cleaned up by prune.

Comment: @DavidThielen At least, it is working for some, according to this recent comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739400/how-do-i-refresh-branches-local-remote-in-visual-studio-when-using-git/33868140#comment78936110_33868140

Comment: VisualStudio is a little flaky when it comes to Git so the answer I guess is this is the way to do it - but it doesn't work sometimes. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 37):

I had remote branches that would not go away even after they were deleted on the server. This tip about setting "Prune remote branches" worked for me. I found it [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/230494/deleted-remote-branches-are-not-removed-from-manag.html).

> Go to Team Explorer, and click Home button. Then Settings > Repository
>   Settings, and set "Prune remote branches during fetch" drop-down to
>   True. Don't forget to click "Update" button to save your edit.

After changing the setting I did a fetch on one of the deleted branches and all of the deleted branches disappeared.

Comment: ^^^ this is the simplest answer

Comment: How can I remove the local branches from from my VS which are not on remote server?

Comment: @AshishShukla, just right click on the branch and click delete, but make sure you are currently on a different branch.

Answer (score 14):

In the newer version of visual studio 2019 for example 16.8.6 you need to go to settings and find git settings as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2015 & 2017

1. Open up Team Explorer and go to the Branches view.
2. Locate the branch you want to delete. Make sure that you aren't
   checked out to that branch-you can't delete the branch you are
   currently working in.
3. Right-click the branch name and select Delete. If you have
   unpublished changes, Visual Studio will ask and make sure you want
   to delete the branch so you don't possibly lose work
   [image]

Comment: This approach scares me because sooner or later someone will delete a branch that is still in use. Is there a way to figure out what branches I have locally that are now gone and delete those?

Comment: Hi i dont think that way....Point 2 clearly states that Make sure that you aren't checked out to that branch-you can't delete the branch you are currently working in.@David Thielen

Comment: In your screenshot above you could delete the develop branch as it's not selected. But I'm guessing doing so would be very bad.

Comment: In the screen shot,only the bugfix i.e selected branch will be deleted.You can see by clicking on the image.@DavidThielen

Comment: My point was you COULD also delete the develop branch this way. Therefore it's a dangerous approach as you can end up deleting a branch still in use.

Comment: Not a bad idea for a single user setup. Unfortunately, in VS2019 Comm. master branches are not displayed in the pane. You can display them by right click > View History where there are a marvelous bunch of options which I will probably never use. Case in point- it was a "simple" wish to edit an incorrect commit message just pushed, and somehow (maybe because can't push until the useless branch is fetched or pulled) ended up with two extra useless branches. We end up reeling from this ridiculous stunted git concept causing massive bloat to all the worlds repos. Rantovani al fine.

Comment: Ehm, that last bit was brought on by a severe case of the late night GITters.