# Showing same branches and code after change git remote url

Tags: git

I have one git repository and now I have to switch the repo code to deploy to other repository and to change the remote URL  I have used below command.

```
git remote set-url origin new.git.url/here
```

Now I can see the remote URL is got changed. But when I do

```
git branch
```

it still shows me the same number of branches and the same code. But the repo is totally new it has only one `master` branch.

So my question is can I refresh the folder/git repository?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prune local tracking branches that do not exist on remote anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064613/how-to-prune-local-tracking-branches-that-do-not-exist-on-remote-anymore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `git remote prune origin` you can remove the local branches that are not on the remote any more.

For more information have a look at this SO question:
[Remove tracking branches no longer on remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726949/remove-tracking-branches-no-longer-on-remote)

Or the official [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-prune).

Comment: Okay... But on running `git branch` it still shows me other branches in the terminal

Comment: @Profer Without more information I can't tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!

I think you need checkout branch what you need to deploy to new repo and push just this branch.

1.Checkout branch.

```
git checkout -b feature_branch_name Edit,
```

2.Add and commit your files.

3.Push your branch to the remote repository:

```
git push -u origin feature_branch_name
```

4.Clone new repo to new folder

```
git clone new_repo_url new_folder
```

Comment: Cloning the new repo to the new folder is what he is trying to avoid as stated in the question.