# The powershell call & operator: set the output encoding

Tags: git, powershell, encoding

When executing directly, everything works as expected:

```
& git status

# OK: "modified:   awél.txt"
```

Storing in a variable

```
$aargh = & git status
$aargh

# NOT OK: "modified:   aw├®l.txt"
```

How can I tell it what encoding to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Character-encoding issues usually don't surface if you print an external program's output to the *screen*, but they may if you *capture* it or send it to another command via the pipeline, because PowerShell decodes the output into .NET strings in the process.

In order for PowerShell to recognize `git`'s output correctly, you must:

- know what character encoding `git` uses in its output
- and set `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to that encoding (on Windows, it defaults to your system's legacy OEM code page).

`git` uses UTF-8, so you must run the following *before* capturing `git`'s output:

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Utf8
```

Note that whether or not you [need to] use `&` to call an external program makes no difference with respect to character-encoding issues.