# How delete a local branch after merging it through a pull request? git-flow, bitbucket, sourcetree

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch, pull-request, git-flow

My environment in local:

- **Git** connecting with **Bitbucket**
- **Sourcetree** with `git-flow`

Steps

1. I create a `feature x` in **Sourcetree** then I add the code.
2. I do a `commit` including the option to `create a pull request` and `push` the changes to `feature x` branch in `remote`.
3. In `pull request` I select the option for `Close {branch} after the pull request is merged`.
4. Within **Bitbucket** a member team approves the `pull request` then merges it into the `develop` branch.
5. I `pull` the new changes to my local `develop` branch.

**NOTE** It's important to review the code through `pull request` before merging it into `develop`, so the question is:

Is there any way to delete automatically the `feature x` branch in my local after made a `pull` in `develop`?

*I tried with a `fetch` but it does not work.

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve? `git branch` output being too crowded with obsolete branches? repo size? something else? Branches (namely, merged ones) weigh virtually nothing in git.

Comment: Sometimes we have projects with 100+ old branches, so, I want to keep organized my local environment as much as possible, so I'm searching the best way to do that automatically, am I clear?

Comment: But if the project itself has many branches, someone cloning it then working on it won't have that many local branches, only the ones they actively checked out locally. And even then, this is only a matter of clearing the branch list output (whay you meant by "organized", if I got it right)

Comment: Yes, you're right, in general, I want to delete automatically the old `branch-features` in my local, after 6 months they can grow up 100-120. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5):

One simple, non-automated way to handle this is to periodically run a branch cleaning command in your local repo, like

```
# to be executed with your "main" stable branch checked out
git branch -d $(git branch --merged)
```

It'll delete every already merged local branch (i.e. those which do NOT have "not yet merged" commits). So all these branches which have been merged through pull requests will be deleted, but not the few ones that have recent (not reviewed/not merged) commits.

*Note :* if your policy is to squash commits upon pull request, this won't be a suitable solution, since your local branches still have the original (pre-squash) commits, so they won't be viewed as merged and won't be deleted.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that command, maybe adding it to a cron job could be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Similar question is already asked elsewhere and there are various useful answers. The point is to find all remote branches marked as 'gone' and then delete them locally.

###### Short answer

This just lists all local branches to delete:

`git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' |  grep -v "\*" | awk '{ print $1; }'`

To delete them, just add `git branch -D`:

`git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' |  grep -v "\*" | awk '{ print $1; }' | xargs -r git branch -D`

**Note:** You should be already on `master` and have fetched your local repo. You can run it before:

`git checkout master && git fetch -p && git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' |  grep -v "\*" | awk '{ print $1; }' | xargs -r git branch -D`

###### Alias

And you can create your own alias for it:

`git config --global alias.delete-gone-branches "! git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' |  grep -v \"*\" | awk '{ print \$1; }' | xargs -r git branch -D"`

And then run just `git delete-gone-branches`.

###### Sources

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30494276/1572749
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38404202/1572749
- https://medium.com/@kcmueller/delete-local-git-branches-that-were-deleted-on-remote-repository-b596b71b530c
- https://www.erikschierboom.com/2020/02/17/cleaning-up-local-git-branches-deleted-on-a-remote/

Comment: In OP's case, use `develop` instead of `master`.