# Is there a way to prune remote-tracking branches that are no longer on remote in Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio

Some tools like SourceTree already prune remote-tracking branches that are no longer present in remote, when I do a fetch.

It seems to be such a simple functionality, yet I can't find any results on whether there is already a button or setting that I can press/enable to make this work.

It's a bit annoying to have to delete the remote-tracking branches whenever the corresponding remote was deleted (most of the times automatically through pull/merge requests).

Does this feature already exist? Or is there a way for me to do some kind of macro where I could execute some kind of Git command when I click on "Fetch" in AS?

**EDIT: Added example for clarification**

Let's say I have a "feature/some_feature" branch. Once I push it, there will be an "origin/feature/some_feature" created. Once that feature is approved and the PR/MR is merged, the "origin" branch is automatically deleted. However, the "feature/some_feature" is still present locally.

Comment: "*I know that there is already a Git command for this - git remote prune origin*" No, this is not true. This command removes only (outdated) remote-tracking branches, not one local branch will be deleted as a result.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll update the question.

Comment: After reading the question, it seemed a bit misleading so I added an example for clarification. Thanks @RomainValeri.

Comment: Although it's not directly integrated with Android Studio, the answer is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064613/how-to-prune-local-tracking-branches-that-do-not-exist-on-remote-anymore

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I came across [this](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10059-git-branch-cleaner) plugin (not promoting). This plugin can be installed in both IntelliJ and Android Studio.

From the plugin's description:

> It will list all branches that do not have tracking remotes and allow you to delete them.

> Each deleted branch will also do a check if it's fully merged to current branch.

> Current branch will not be listed.

> Branches that are not merged to HEAD are not selected by default.

It doesn't delete/prune remote-tracking branches automatically with a Git Fetch, but it will list all of them and allow you to delete them in a separate window.

Kudos to the dev.