# Delete first character from a text file

Tags: bash

[image: text file]

I have a text file in which the first character - I want to delete, but I am not getting either its a CR or LF character, how Can I delete the file character from the entire file.

Comment: Do you want to delete it in python or bash?

Comment: using bash is easy - so bash

Comment: Deleted python tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete the first five characters on any line of a text file in Linux with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3795512/608639)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `tail` command:

```
tail -c +2 file.txt > newfile.txt
```

The `-c` option says to count by characters rather than lines, and `+2` means to output the tail starting from character 2.

Comment: Wow, does this not do a lot of rewriting?

Comment: How else do you expect to do it? Unix doesn't provide any way to shift the bytes of a file directly.

Comment: BTW, what this character ? @Barmar

Comment: It's quite curious. Python provides a utility called `fileinput` that entertains inline edits to a file. I thought there must be a bash utility similar to that, maybe with sed or cut.

Comment: @hassan: In situations like this, I find it's usually instructive to view the file in a hex editor. Most likely, there's an unprintable character present, and the hex editor will allow you to see which one.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You can use `ed` from a shell script. But it still has to do all the same rewriting -- it reads the whole file into memory, you do your edits, then it writes the memory back to the file.

Comment: The tricky thing is that tools like `sed` and `ed` operate on lines, not characters. So if the first character in the file is a newline, it's more complicated to delete it with these tools.

Comment: And the `fileinput` utility has to do this as well. There simply isn't a way on Unix to directly modify a file's contents, it's all done by reading and writing.

Comment: one caveat is that it only does it for the first line of the txt file

Comment: @MonaJalal That's what they said they wanted.

Answer (score 0):

in python, you could open the file as a string, remove the first character, and wirte the file again.

```
myfile = open("yourfilehere", "r")
mylist = myfile.readlines()
mytext = ""
for items in mylist:
    mytext = mytext + items +"\n"
myfile.close()
mytext = mytext[1:]
myfile = open("yourfilehere", "w")
myfile.write(mytext)
```

Comment: i wrote this before you removed the python tag.. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If the first character that you want to delete is on the first line only, use the `tail` command. `tail -c +2` will do the job.

```
<oldFile tail -c +2 >newFile
```

If the first character that you want to delete is on every line of the file, use the `sed` command. `sed -e 's/^.//'` will do the job.

```
<oldFile sed -e 's/^.//' >newFile
```

If the first character that you want to delete is on some lines of the file, and it is a specific character, again use the `sed` command. For example, you might want to remove a leading space from each line that has leading space.

```
<oldFile sed -e 's/^ //' >newFile
```