# Remove first character of a text file from shell

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a text file and I would like to only delete the first character of the text file, is there a way to do this in shell script?

I'm new to writing scripts so I really don't know where to start. I understand that the main command most people use is "sed" but I can only find how to use that as a find and replace tool.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: So then find the first character and replace it with nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a unix command for deleting the first N characters of a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/971879/608639)

Answer (score 18):

You can use the `tail` command, telling it to start from character 2:

```
tail -c +2 infile > outfile
```

Comment: This works faster than the `dd` based solution

Answer (score 10):

You can use `sed`

```
sed '1s/^.//' startfile > endfile
```

- `1s` means match line `1`, in substitution mode (`s`)
- `^.` means at the beginning of the line (`^`), match any character (`.`)
- There's nothing between the last slashes, which means substitute with nothing (remove)

Comment: here you don't need the `^`, the first char replaced is by definition is the first char.

Comment: You don't even need to anchor with `^` - but you do need to do something different if the first character is a newline: `sed -e '1{' -e '/^$/d' -e 's/.//' -e '}'`.

Answer (score 3):

I used to use cut command to do this.

For example:

```
cat file|cut -c2-80
```

Will show characters from column 2 to 80 only.

In your case you can use:

```
cat file|cut -c2-10000 > newfile
```

I hope this help you.

[]s

Comment: Question only wants to remove the first character of the *file*, not of each *line*.

Comment: Ps: This command removes first characters on each line of a file. I misunderstood the question but maybe it can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `0,addr2` address-range to limit replacements to the first substitution, e.g.

```
sed '0,/./s/^.//' file
```

That will remove the 1st character of the file and the `sed` expression will be at the end of its range -- effectively replacing only the 1st occurrence.

To edit the file in place, use the `-i` option, e.g.

```
sed -i '0,/./s/^.//' file
```

or simply redirect the output to a new file:

```
sed '0,/./s/^.//' file > newfile
```

Comment: This only works if the first character is not a newline - you really need `/^$/d` within there for that case.

Comment: @TobySpeight - not so. `'\n'` is a line ending and is not counted as a character. Give it a try `printf "\n\nCrackers&Cheese\n" | sed '0,/./s/^.//'` yields `"rackers&Cheese". I also note your solution fails for that very case.

Comment: Ah, so you're taking a record-oriented view of the word, where newlines are merely record separators?  That wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 2):

A few other ideas:

```
awk '{print (NR == 1 ? substr($0,2) : $0)}' file

perl -0777 -pe 's/.//' file

perl -pe 's/.// unless $done; $done = 1' file

ed file <<END
1s/.//
w
q
END
```

Answer (score 2):

`dd` allows you to specify an offset at which to start reading:

```
dd ibs=1 seek=1 if="$input" of="$output"
```

(where the variables are set to point to your input and output files, respectively)

Comment: This works for me: `dd bs=1 skip=1 if="$input" of="$output"`